# Being vs Getting difference

Tags: grammar, difference

What is the difference between these two words??

Examples:

Man **getting** eaten by crocodile.

Man **being** eaten by crocodile.

Answer (score 0):

- **Being** is the present participle of **be**.
- **Getting** is the present participle of **get**.

So the only difference is the different definitions of **be** and **get**.

- **To be** is to exist or to happen.
- **To get** is to receive something.

So the difference is very minimal, but **getting** eaten is more as if the man is *receiving* the shark attack rather than *experiencing* it.

Comment: Unfortunately, while this seems reasonable, I don't think it actually describes current English. _Get_ is a (somewhat informal) alternative for _be_ in forming passives. Sometimes there is a nuance of meaning, but it depends on the verb. _He got heard_ suggests that he overcame some obstacles or challenges to be heard; but _He got left behind_ doesn't have that implication at all.